# Write $\epsilon_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta} F^{\mu\nu} F^{\alpha\beta}$ as a total divergence $\partial_\mu G^\mu$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, tensor-calculus

I have the following homework problem in theoretical electrodynamics:

> Show that the gauge invariant Lagrange density $\epsilon_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta} F^{\mu\nu} F^{\alpha\beta}$ can be written as a total divergence of a four-vector.

This total divergence should be something like $\partial_\mu G^\mu$, right?

With
$$
\hat F^{\mu\nu} = \frac 12 \epsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta} F_{\alpha\beta}
$$
I figured that I write this Lagrange density (I'll refer to it as $L_2$) could be written as:
$$
L_2 = 2 \hat F^{\mu\nu} F_{\mu\nu}
$$

I simplified this by using the matrix representations of each $F$ and got it down to:
$$
L_2 = -\frac 4c B_i E^i
$$

$B$ and $E$ can be expressed in Terms of $A$ like so:
$$
B_i = \epsilon_{ijk} \partial_j A^j
,\quad
E_i = -\partial_i A^0 -\partial_0 A^i
$$

How would I continue to find that four-vector $G$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write $$F_{\mu\nu} = \partial_{[\mu}A_{\nu ]} $$ Then your Lagrange density is $${ \mathcal{L}} = \epsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}\partial_{[\mu}A_{\nu ]}\partial_{[\alpha}A_{\beta ]}$$

Now we want a vector whose divergence is ${ \mathcal{L}}$.  The $\partial_{\mu}$ looks promising, so we ask if we can bring that outside so it acts on the remaining vector, i.e. $${ \mathcal{L}} = \partial_{\mu}(\epsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}A_{\nu }\partial_{[\alpha}A_{\beta ]}) \ \ (1)$$  We don't need to worry that we've lost the antisymmetrization brackets on $\mu$ and $\nu$ because the epsilon symbol forces this.

As you pointed out, this isn't quite what we started with because we have an additional term of the form $$(\epsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}A_{\nu }\partial_{\mu}\partial_{[\alpha}A_{\beta ]}) $$  However the total antisymmetry of the epsilon symbol means we can treat the $\mu$ $\alpha$ $\beta$ contribution as $$\partial_{[\mu}F_{\alpha\beta]} $$ which vanishes due to the Maxwell equations.  Hence the anzatz (1) holds.  (The vector whose divergence we take looks like the abelian Chern Simons current).

Comment: You mean $\partial_\mu G^\mu = \partial_{[\mu} \epsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta} A_{\nu]} \partial_{[\alpha} A_{\beta]}$ and that is it? But then that $\partial_\mu$ acts onto the $A_\beta$ as well. Don't I need to write $\epsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta} (\partial_{[\mu} A_{\nu]}) (\partial_{[\alpha}A_{\beta]})$ which then prevents this pulling out?

Comment: If you write $G^{\mu} = \epsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}A_{\nu}\partial_{[\alpha}A_{\beta]}$  then $\partial_{\mu}G^{\mu}$ is what you want.  The epsilon automatically antisymmetrizes $\mu$ and $\nu$ for you.

Comment: In your definition of $F$, the $\partial$ only acts on $A$. But with that $G$, the $\partial_\mu$ will act on both $A_\nu$ and $A\beta$ with the product rule. Or does some (anti-)symmetry remove that part?

Comment: Right, so you will get some terms like $\partial_{[\mu}F_{\alpha]\beta}$, but the epsilon will fully antisymmetrize over $\mu$, $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and this vanishes by Maxwell equations.

Comment: That last point ought to be incorporated in your answer.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty OK as it was a homework question I was trying to keep the answer as lean as possible, but now it's pretty much there I should maybe beef it up a bit...

Comment: Okay, *this* is where I have to use the Bianchi-Identity given on the problem set. That makes totally sense now!

Comment: I made a Penrose Diagram [for this problem](http://wstaw.org/m/2013/01/20/bianchi.png). I can see the Bianchi identity there pretty well.